# How to remote debug my application with an IDE?

Tags: install4j

Today I wanted to remote debug my installed application to find a bug during runtime. Therefore I tried to add the following VM parameters at the command line parameters as well as adding them to the vmoption file:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

To connect remotely I used the Eclipse IDE and checked the VM parameters with the java Visual VM tools. They seems to be committed correctly but have no effect to the application. I could not connect to the application from my IDE. So now the question: is it possible to debug remotely an application installed by install4j? Have anybody tried it and was successful?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put each VM parameter on a separate line in the vmoption file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also activated the "passthrough vm parameters" option for the launcher itself. We are using install4j version 6.0.1.

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue? There is no problem with such VM parameters in principle, they are just passed on to the JVM.

Comment: A firewall indeed would cause the connection problem, but the "suspend" parameter is also ignored and the application starts normally without waiting for any connection.

Comment: Please try to add "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" to bin/install4jc.vmoptions in the install4j installation directory and run bin/install4jc. I see "listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" being printed on the terminal and the JVM is suspended.

Comment: It seems that for java 8 only the following parameter are necessary: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005`. With this parameter set to the vmoptions the IDE is able to attach to the application and I can debug through the code.